# rails + postgres: should I add index in a large table for the foreign key to a small table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, indexing

My User table has about a million records.

My Region table has maybe 200 records.

Should I `add_index :users, :region_id` ?

And if it was the other way round where a region has a user_id, should I index the user_id in the region table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should add. If you think to you are going to have lot of query that got condition for those fields.
In your case I think you might have lot queries like people living in one region, so I would create a index on users table for (id(user_id) and region_id fields together in one single index)

```
add_index :users, [:id, :user_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil".
Add an index only if profiling of your application indicates that you need one.